Hierarchy Problem vs ratio of masses in the Standard Model
In the Standard Model, the ratio between the top quark's mass to the neutrinos is at least about $2 \times 10^{11}$. It could rise by at least an order of magnitude in the coming years as the sensitivity of experiments measuring the neutrino masses increases.
This is only a couple of orders of magnitude less than the ratio of the supposed GUT scale to the mass of the Higgs, at approximately $10^{14}$.
Is the large ratio of masses in the Standard Model an example of a hierarchy problem in the usual sense?

You are implicitly proposing something in the dark about the RG evolution of Yukawa couplings, but I couldn't guess what... Are you trying to model it on the Georgi-Glashow model?

I can promise you that if so, it is entirely unintentional, as I have no knowledge of the details of that :P

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27453/technical-naturalness-of-yukawa-couplings (the Yukawa couplings determine the fermion masses, once the Higgs mass is set -- although the neutrinos are a special case as explained there).
